# how to make different toast when clicking on different items in a listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

hello guys am getting problem in keeping my position items FIXED when am trying to search for an item in my listview.Example: when i am clicking on an item(akim performance) in my listview i get a toast of string (This is really good;at position3),WITHOUT search interface; which is good.However, when i used search interface for the same item(i get a different toast of string at another (position0).How can i keep position along with the toast of string SAME that is fixed for each of them!!

In short my aim is when i click on"akim performance" without and with search interface,it should both give me the toast(This is really good)! thanks..help me guys

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private EditText editText;

private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.event6icon);

editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCourseText);

ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.CoursesListView);

String [] listViewAdapterContent = {
        "rita performance",
        "ashely performance",
        "jenifer performance",
        "akim performance",
        "john performance",

    };

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, listViewAdapterContent);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
    String sMessage = "";
    switch(position) {
    case 0: sMessage = "This is exactly what should be done "; break;
    case 1: sMessage = "You are completely wrong! "; break;
    case 2: sMessage = "This is good "; break;
    case 3: sMessage = "This is really good "; break;
    case 4: sMessage = "This is perfect "; break;
   }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sMessage+position,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
        });

   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count,  int  after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
        MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
    }
});
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may use simple random chooser logic with in your code like this;**

```
 itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {

                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is exactly what should be done "+position,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
                else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are completely wrong! "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

            }
        });
```

Comment: what if i have more than 2 items say(100)?? i updated my codes above. should we not use else if then?if yes how??

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by GökcanD, you can use a simple random number generator, but use a [`Switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement if you've got lots of possibilities:

```
itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {

        switch (Random.nextInt(5) + 1) {
            case 1: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is exactly what should be done "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); break;
            case 2: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are completely wrong! "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); break;
            case 3: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is good "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); break;
            case 4: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is really good "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); break;
            case 5: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is perfect"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); break;
            default: break;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: hi it worked very well ,however please check i have edited my question can you guide me on that?

Comment: You should try not to post questions that are a moving target. The answers now no longer correspond to the new edited question. Rather, you should accept an answer, as you have, and post a new question.

Comment: Sorry sir but i had already posted the question here but i got no response.please help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382464/how-to-keep-position-fixed-when-searchingsearch-interface-for-a-particular-ite/34392200#34392200

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 5 items in a listview and onclick of each item, you would like to show a different toast message. Try this:

```
itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
        String sMessage = "";
        switch(position) {
            case 0: sMessage = "This is exactly what should be done "; break;
            case 1: sMessage = "You are completely wrong! "; break;
            case 2: sMessage = "This is good "; break;
            case 3: sMessage = "This is really good "; break;
            case 4: sMessage = "This is perfect "; break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sMessage+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: hi it worked very well ,however please check i have edited my question can you guide me on that?